# How to change values of a numpy array between two positions

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a numpy array full of 0's such as this

```
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

And a list of positions such as this

```
   [2-4,6-10]
```

So what I want to do is iterate through the list of positions and then change the 0's in the numpy array to 1's within the according positions so that I should have a numpy array such as.

```
  [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

Hope this is clear enough, if not just let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Your "list of positions" is effectively `[-2, 6, 10]` (because `2-4` is -2).  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant 2-4 and then 6-10 so the positions would be the second to the forth and then the sixth to the tenth. Thanks

Comment: So how do you represent the `2-4` in python? (the way you represent it will change the answer)

Comment: That still doesn't make sense.  If you type `[2-4,6-10]` into the Python interpreter and evaluate it you will get `[-2, -4]`.  What data structure do you actually have?  Do you have a list of strings?

Comment: Your output array seems a little inconsistent. Are you sure it's correct? 2-4 covers positions 2 through 4 and 6-10 only covers positions 7 through 10

Comment: You need to make up your mind about what you mean by `2`. Is it by 0-based indexing or 1-based indexing. Also, at this moment, the output has one more element than the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list of pairs to hold the positions;

```
l = [(2, 4), (6, 10)]
nl = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Secondly, use a loop;

```
for a in l:
  for c, n in enumerate(nl) 
    if (a[0] >= c || a[1] <= c):
       nl[c] = 1
```

This is by far not the fastest way to do this but it is simple and readable.

As suggested by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) you could use this instead, which is a lot better in my opinion;

```
nl[a[0]:[a[1]]=[1]*(a[1]-a[0])
```

Comment: This slice assignment might be faster: `nl[a[0]:[a[1]]=[1]*(a[1]-a[0])`

Comment: Sorry - I fixed it now

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach by generating those indices as a concatenated array with [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and then indexing and assigning `1s` -

```
In [64]: a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

In [65]: pos = np.r_[1:4,5:10]

In [66]: a[pos] = 1

In [67]: a
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: this is a trivial fix; OP needs till index `10`. so, it should be `np.r_[1:4, 5:10]`. As a side note, we could also use `range()`

Comment: @kmario23 OP has `12` elems in input, while `13` in output. So, we need some clarification on it from OP. Posted comment on the same. Changing the ranges should be trivial anyway, so I would leave it to OP to make the needed edits.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the discrepancy. But from his index positions `[2-4, 6-10]` it is somehow clear that he needs 5 elements (6-10) regardless of the input/output size. Seems like he's following matlab based convention for the index